# Access Data on Queueable class

Tags: apex, queueable-apex

I'm playing around with Queueable class to possibly implement in a upcoming project.

Here is what am trying to do.

I have a Queueable class.

```
public class SampleQueueble implements Queueable {

    public static List<String> sampleC = new List<String>();

    public SampleQueueble(List<String> objList){
        sampleC.addAll(objList);
        system.debug('sampleC->'+sampleC);
        system.debug('objList->'+objList);
    }


    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {         
        system.debug('sampleC ->'+sampleC);

    }

}
```

And I'm calling it as follows, where I want to pass a List to a Queueable class. And here's how I call it.

```
public List<String> listS = new List<String>();
listS.add('abz');
listS.add('aqz');
listS.add('aez');
listS.add('atz');

system.debug('listS->'+listS);
ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new SampleQueueble(listS));
system.debug('listS->'+listS);
system.debug('jobID ->'+jobID);
```

But I cannot retrieve the `listS` List on the `Queueable` class even though I pass it together with the constructor. It simply doesn't call the constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couple things. You need the `List<String>` to be an *instance* property, not a `static` one. I would also move the instantiation to reside solely in the constructor.

```
public class SampleQueueble implements Queueable
{
    public final List<String> data;
    public SampleQueueble(List<String> input)
    {
        data = input;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context)
    {         
        system.debug('data ->'+data);
    }
}
```